# Query in SQL Server 2014 for a report (I need the last ROW of a table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I have a problem with a query.

[image]

I want to have in my report, ALL the items of the order with `ID_Order = 9` that have been delivered. And for the items that have been delivered at two times (Item Code = Art3 for example), I just want to have the last row, that means the last delivery of this Item, with NO repetition.

I already tried these two queries without success:

Attempt #1: DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Order.ItemCode, Delivery. Qty, Delivery.ID_Delivery, 
    Order.ID_Order
FROM 
    Delivery
INNER JOIN
    Order ON Order.ID_Order = Delivery.ID_Order 
WHERE
    Order.ID_Order = '9'
```

Attempt #2: subquery

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT
         Order.ItemCode, Delivery.Qty, 
     FROM
         Delivery 
     INNER JOIN
         Order ON Order.ID_Order = Delivery.ID_Order
     WHERE
         Order.ID_Order = '9')
GROUP BY 
    a.ItemCode, a.Qty
```

Comment: What I am unable to understand why you are ditching `ar2` for `id_delivery= 23`. What is the condition for that. What is your requirements ?

Comment: What are the criteria for selecting the last delivery? On what basis one can tell the last delivery?

Comment: Or if you just want desired result then just do the grouping on `id_order,itemcode` and `select max(id_Delivery),max(qty),other columns`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query --

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT C.ID_Order
        ,D.ID_Delivery
        ,C.ItemCode
        ,C.Quantity
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY C.ItemCode ORDER BY D.ID_Delivery DESC
            ) AS RowNum
    FROM Customer_Order C
    INNER JOIN Delivery D ON C.ID_Order = D.ID_Order
        AND C.ItemCode = D.ItemCode
    WHERE C.ID_Order = 9
    )
SELECT ID_Order
    ,ID_Delivery
    ,ItemCode
    ,Quantity
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Order.ItemCode, Delivery. Qty, Delivery.ID_Delivery, 
    Order.ID_Order
FROM 
    Delivery
INNER JOIN
    Order ON Order.ID_Order = Delivery.ID_Order 
WHERE
    Order.ID_Order = '9'
AND Delivery.ID_Delivery IN 
(
 SELECT MAX(ID_Delivery) FROM Delivery D WHERE D.ID_Order = Delivery.ID_Order GROUP BY D.ID_Order
)
```

I hope it will work for you.